# TabControl и DataGrid

Tags: sql, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid, tabcontrol

Всем привет. Реализую проект на WPF с использованием Entity Framework. На одном из окон было решено сделать вывод сразу нескольких таблиц. Было предложено сделать это через TabControl и его вкладки. Прикладываю код реализации:

```
 private void Table_Update()
    {
        if (Tables.SelectedItem == usersTab)
        {
            context.Users.Load();
            UsersGrid.ItemsSource = context.Users.Local;
        }
        else if (Tables.SelectedItem == goodsTab)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Пук");
            context.Goods.Load();
            GoodsGrid.ItemsSource = context.Goods.Local;
        }
        else if (Tables.SelectedItem == creatorsTab)
        {
            context.Creators.Load();
            CreatorsGrid.ItemsSource = context.Creators.Local;
        }
    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Table_Update();
    }
```

Проблема заключается в том, что загружается только таблица Users, остальные, как бы я не нажимал, подгружаться не хотят. С чем может быть связана проблема и как её решить?

Comment: Внимательно посмотрите на свою логику, что видите? Просто пропишите ее словами. Вот я вижу: `При полной загрузке окна вызвать метод Table_Update(). В самом методе смотрим на SelectedItem и на его основе делаем действия`. Ключевое тут "При полной загрузке окна". Вы окно повторно открываете? Думаю нет. Почему тогда думаете, что это событие должно вызваться (а с ним вместе и ваш метод) при переключении вкладок? Хотите переключения вкладок, смотрите события самого `TabControl`, например... `SelectionChanged`. Ну а вообще, WPF это привязки, и все в этом духе, зря вы так вот в коде контролы дергаете

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!